# Syntax to add objects to a list?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out the syntax to add a complex object into a list. Here's what I know works:

```
ComplexObject temp = new ComplexObject() {attribute1 = 5, attribute2 = 6};
ComplexObjectList.Add(temp);
```

Here's what I'm wanting to do instead:

```
ComplexObjectList.Add(new ComplexObject(){attribute1 = 5, attribute2 = 6});
```

I realize that it doesn't work, but is there any other way to add one to my list without creating one before hand? I have no need for temp other than this one function call.

Comment: _" realize that it doesn't work"_  But it works this way.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Your syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: How can you insert something that you have never created

Comment: If attribute1 and attribute2 are visible properties or attributes, your later example would work.  What type of error are you seeing?  "Realizing it doesn't work" doesn't tell us much, an error would let us know if the class was ill-constructed.

Comment: The way your two snippets are currently written, they are completely equivalent. If the first works, the second should too. The problem is probably some trivial typo somewhere. Are you sure this is the actual failing code? Maybe you could include the compiler error you get so we can better identify the problem.

Comment: My guess: `ComplexObjectList` is a type (that doesn't have a static `Add` method) instead of a reference of type `ComplexObjectList`.

Comment: @Tergiver: i wonder if that's his casing throwing off the example and he didn't mean that ComplexObjectList was a List<ComplexObject> (i.e. `var ComplexObjectList = new List<ComplexObject>();`

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare right, they say the first one works.. I suppose we just have to wait for a definition of "doesn't work".

Comment: Note that even if your code looks like the "what I'm wanting to do instead" example (which is legal, as others have noted), the compiler will still create the `temp` variable implicitly.

Comment: @phoog: true, it's syntactical candy.

Comment: I guess the main point is, the OP should let us know what his error was.  Assuming his 1st example compiled, so should his second.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a silly mistake. I was attempting to use an IList as a List without specifically declaring it as a List so that's where my confusion was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. If not, then the problem is probably in the declaration of ComplexObjectList.
Should be: `List<ComplexObject> ComplexObjectList = new List<ComplexObject>();`
Also make sure the class properties are public.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have this class (main point being must be an accessible constructor and the properties you wish to set must be visible):

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And you have this list:

```
var listOfPoint = new List<Point>();
```

Then you can, as your second example ponders, do this:

```
listOfPoint.Add(new Point { X = 13, Y = 7 });
```

Which is *roughly* (there are some slight differences, Eric Lippert has some good reads on this) equivalent to your first example:

```
var temp = new Point { X = 13, Y = 7 };
listOfPoint.Add(temp);
```

In fact, you could add the point at the time the list is constructed as well:

```
var listOfPoint = new List<Point>
    {
         new Point { X = 7, Y = 13 }
    };
```

Now the fact that you say you "realize that it doesn't work" is puzzling because your initializer syntax is correct, so I'm not sure if you're asking before trying it, or if there is an issue with the declaration of your list or your class that is throwing you off.  That said, if your first code snippet compiled, technically so should your second.